# Progress 4GL Column Names

Tags: database, progress-4gl, openedge

I'm having an issue with a a query I'm trying to run in 4GL.

This works

```
FOR EACH platte.item_branch NO-LOCK
   WHERE item_branch.item_ptr = 23546:

   DISPLAY
     item_branch.system_id LABEL "bar" "|SEP|"
     item_branch.item_ptr LABEL "foobar"
    WITH WIDTH 122.

END.
```

And this doesn't

```
FOR EACH platte.item_branch NO-LOCK
   WHERE item_branch.item_ptr = 23546:

   DISPLAY
     item_branch.system_id LABEL "minor" "|SEP|"
     item_branch.load_factor LABEL "foobar"
    WITH WIDTH 122.

END.
```

Is there anything in ABL that would cause a field to start with load_ to not work? I have confirmed that any field that starts with load_ will not return data.  It will error out everytime.

Comment: you need to post the error - I'm not seeing anything here which would result in an error.

Comment: As @TimKuehn said, you need to post the error. Also post the version of OpenEdge you are working with

Comment: I'm not getting an error.  We are using a custom python script to send all to to our open edge server.  We are using 11.3 I think

Comment: You said that it "errors out"...

Comment: It crashes our python scripts on return from the progress server.  I'm just trying to figure out why.  We are going to have to find another solution. Thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: After doing more digging this morning.  I found out that LABEL is being overridden, and not using the label I requested for load_factor is always being returned as "Load Factor" not "foobar".

Comment: I finally found a solution.  I had to declare a variable and put the field inside the variable to be able to use it.  I don't like it, but it is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such feature.  Fields starting with "load_" work fine.